# Symfony2 optional routes

Tags: symfony, routes

As Symfony Book suggests (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders), in order to create an optionar placeholder to use in a route you simply have to do something like that:

```
participant_list:
       pattern:  /list/{filter}/
       defaults: { _controller: ParticipantBundle:Default:list, filter: 1}
```

And define that variable in the controller:

```
public function listAction($filter) {
…
}
```

But, when I access to mypage.dev/list/, without parameters it says "no route found for GET /list/".

Do you know any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but the url must be mypage.dev/list with no slash at the end, and the routing should be

```
participant_list:
   pattern:  /list/{filter}
   defaults: { _controller: ParticipantBundle:Default:list, filter: 1}
```

Comment: That's weird because I made some test and it was working.But I don't know symfony that much, sorry

Comment: In fact, you're right in some way. But, if I don't put that slash at the end, (in routing), when I access /list/ (with the slash), then it throws the 404

Comment: I really advise you to remove the ending slash. If you generate your URL with router (as shown in documentation), you won't get 404 error as default generated URL will be /list and call listAction(1)...

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the default value of the variable in the controller:

```
public function listAction($filter = 1) {
  …
}
```